# ISO schematron could not validate processing instructions in XML document

Tags: xml, validation, xslt, schematron

**Requirement Description**: our requirement is to looks for the processing instruction whose target is PubTbl and which have got pseudo-attribute @rth in input xml document. These processing instructions are specific to Arbortext Editor and they present all over the XML document with in tables.

```xml
<?PubTbl row rht="0.76in"?>
```

We have noticed that at processing-instructions in our xml document our ISO Schematron schema (mentioned below) is not getting fired.

- Does n't ISO Schematron validate processing instruction?
- If ISO Schematron validates processing instructions, is there any
  setting/param change i need to take care?

## ISO Schematron schema

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" id="vert-space-tables_schema"
    queryBinding="xslt2" schemaVersion="iso">
    <title>Forcing vertical space in content within tables</title>
    <pattern id="vert-space-tables_pattern">
        <title>Forcing vertical space in content within tables</title>
        <rule id="vert-space-tables_processing-inst_rule" context="processing-instruction('PubTbl')"
            abstract="false">
            <report test="contains(.,'rht=')"> 
                The table have got processing instructions you are looking altered to modify
                pagination. </report>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

I am using the ISO schematron stylesheets present in the "ant-schematron-2010-04-14.jar" zip file attached, using ant task

```xml
   <taskdef name="schematron" classname="com.schematron.ant.SchematronTask"
        classpath="${lib}/ant-schematron-2010-04-14.jar; ${lib}/resolver.jar"/>

<schematron schema="${schema}/vert-space-tables/vert-space-tables.sch" failonerror="false"
            queryLanguageBinding="xslt2" format="svrl" OutputDir="${dist}/vert-space-tables"
            outputFilename="fail.xml" debugMode="true" failOnError="false" diagnose="true" classpathref="saxon-loc">
            <fileset dir="${xml}/vert-space-tables" includes="Forcing_vertical_space_in_content_within_tables-fail.xml"/>            
            </schematron>
```

"debug.xslt" - also attached is the XSL stylesheets generated from ISO schematron and validated against the xml document.

With in debug.xslt (at bottom of the file), I have noticed that apply-templates only processes element nodes that way it never gets to processing-instrucitons gets handled, is this why?

```xml
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="-2" mode="M1">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="*****" mode="M1"/>
           </xsl:template>
```

**debug.xslt content Below:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:schold="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron"
                xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
                xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                version="2.0"><!--Implementers: please note that overriding process-prolog or process-root is 
    the preferred method for meta-stylesheets to use where possible. -->
<xsl:param name="archiveDirParameter"/>
   <xsl:param name="archiveNameParameter"/>
   <xsl:param name="fileNameParameter"/>
   <xsl:param name="fileDirParameter"/>
   <xsl:variable name="document-uri">
      <xsl:value-of select="document-uri(/)"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <!--PHASES-->


<!--PROLOG-->
<xsl:output xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
               method="xml"
               omit-xml-declaration="no"
               standalone="yes"
               indent="yes"/>

   <!--XSD TYPES FOR XSLT2-->


<!--KEYS AND FUNCTIONS-->


<!--DEFAULT RULES-->


<!--MODE: SCHEMATRON-SELECT-FULL-PATH-->
<!--This mode can be used to generate an ugly though full XPath for locators-->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="schematron-select-full-path">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="schematron-get-full-path"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <!--MODE: SCHEMATRON-FULL-PATH-->
<!--This mode can be used to generate an ugly though full XPath for locators-->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="schematron-get-full-path">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="schematron-get-full-path"/>
      <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="namespace-uri()=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>*:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            <xsl:text>[namespace-uri()='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri()"/>
            <xsl:text>']</xsl:text>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:variable name="preceding"
                    select="count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())                                   and namespace-uri() = namespace-uri(current())])"/>
      <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="1+ $preceding"/>
      <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*" mode="schematron-get-full-path">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="schematron-get-full-path"/>
      <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="namespace-uri()=''">@<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>@*[local-name()='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            <xsl:text>' and namespace-uri()='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri()"/>
            <xsl:text>']</xsl:text>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <!--MODE: SCHEMATRON-FULL-PATH-2-->
<!--This mode can be used to generate prefixed XPath for humans-->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="schematron-get-full-path-2">
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
         <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
         <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[name(.)=name(current())]">
            <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name(.)=name(current())])+1"/>
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:if test="not(self::*)">
         <xsl:text/>/@<xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
   <!--MODE: SCHEMATRON-FULL-PATH-3-->
<!--This mode can be used to generate prefixed XPath for humans 
    (Top-level element has index)-->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="schematron-get-full-path-3">
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
         <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
         <xsl:if test="parent::*">
            <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name(.)=name(current())])+1"/>
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:if test="not(self::*)">
         <xsl:text/>/@<xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <!--MODE: GENERATE-ID-FROM-PATH -->
<xsl:template match="/" mode="generate-id-from-path"/>
   <xsl:template match="text()" mode="generate-id-from-path">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="generate-id-from-path"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('.text-', 1+count(preceding-sibling::text()), '-')"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="comment()" mode="generate-id-from-path">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="generate-id-from-path"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('.comment-', 1+count(preceding-sibling::comment()), '-')"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()" mode="generate-id-from-path">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="generate-id-from-path"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('.processing-instruction-', 1+count(preceding-sibling::processing-instruction()), '-')"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*" mode="generate-id-from-path">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="generate-id-from-path"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('.@', name())"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*" mode="generate-id-from-path" priority="-0.5">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="generate-id-from-path"/>
      <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('.',name(),'-',1+count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())]),'-')"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <!--MODE: GENERATE-ID-2 -->
<xsl:template match="/" mode="generate-id-2">U</xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*" mode="generate-id-2" priority="2">
      <xsl:text>U</xsl:text>
      <xsl:number level="multiple" count="*"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="node()" mode="generate-id-2">
      <xsl:text>U.</xsl:text>
      <xsl:number level="multiple" count="*"/>
      <xsl:text>n</xsl:text>
      <xsl:number count="node()"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*" mode="generate-id-2">
      <xsl:text>U.</xsl:text>
      <xsl:number level="multiple" count="*"/>
      <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="string-length(local-name(.))"/>
      <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(name(),':','.')"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <!--Strip characters--><xsl:template match="text()" priority="-1"/>

   <!--SCHEMA SETUP-->
<xsl:template match="/">
      <svrl:schematron-output xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
                              title="Forcing vertical space in content within tables"
                              schemaVersion="iso">
         <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="$archiveDirParameter"/>   
         <xsl:value-of select="$archiveNameParameter"/>  
         <xsl:value-of select="$fileNameParameter"/>  
         <xsl:value-of select="$fileDirParameter"/>
         </xsl:comment>
         <svrl:active-pattern>
            <xsl:attribute name="document">
               <xsl:value-of select="document-uri(/)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">vert-space-tables_pattern</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">Forcing vertical space in content within tables</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </svrl:active-pattern>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="M1"/>
      </svrl:schematron-output>
   </xsl:template>

   <!--SCHEMATRON PATTERNS-->
<svrl:text xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl">Forcing vertical space in content within tables</svrl:text>

   <!--PATTERN vert-space-tables_patternForcing vertical space in content within tables-->
<svrl:text xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl">Forcing vertical space in content within tables</svrl:text>

      <!--RULE vert-space-tables_processing-inst_rule-->
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PubTbl')" priority="1000" mode="M1">
      <svrl:fired-rule xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
                       context="processing-instruction('PubTbl')"
                       id="vert-space-tables_processing-inst_rule"/>

            <!--REPORT -->
<xsl:if test="contains(., 'breakpenalty=&#34;-10000&#34;') or contains(., 'breakpenalty=&#34;2000&#34;') or contains(.,'rht=')">
         <svrl:successful-report xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
                                 test="contains(., 'breakpenalty=&#34;-10000&#34;') or contains(., 'breakpenalty=&#34;2000&#34;') or contains(.,'rht=')">
            <xsl:attribute name="location">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="schematron-select-full-path"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <svrl:text> 
                The table have got processing instructions you are looking altered to modify
                pagination. </svrl:text>
         </svrl:successful-report>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="M1"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="text()" priority="-1" mode="M1"/>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="-2" mode="M1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="M1"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks and regards,
Suresh.

Comment: You say you're trying to match @rth, but the test is for "rht="? When I tested your schematron with the test and PI reconciled it worked just fine.

Comment: Clarified the requirement a bit.

Comment: @nine9ths: Thanks for your response. have you made any setting modifications for processing-instructions to get recognized? Just to update my findings, the xml document fired processing instruction rules in Oxygen XML editor, but the same document when passed through ant "ant-schematron-2010-04-14.jar", in the svrl output i noticed that these processing-instructions in the document are not fired. shown below is my svrl output when used

Comment: {<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svrl:schematron-output xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
                        ...  title="Forcing vertical space in content within tables" schemaVersion="iso">
                       
<svrl:active-pattern
document="file:/D:/Topic/Schematron/My%20Exercise/Schematron%20Project/Java%20solution%20using%20Ant/xml/vert-space-tables/Forcing_vertical_space_in_content_within_tables-fail.xml"
id="vert-space-tables_pattern"
name="Forcing vertical space in content within tables"
/>
</svrl:schematron-output>}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to duplicate this problem when I run this schematron file (copied from above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" id="vert-space-tables_schema"
  queryBinding="xslt2" schemaVersion="iso">
  <title>Forcing vertical space in content within tables</title>
  <pattern id="vert-space-tables_pattern">
    <title>Forcing vertical space in content within tables</title>
    <rule id="vert-space-tables_processing-inst_rule" context="processing-instruction('PubTbl')"
      abstract="false">
      <report test="contains(.,'rht=')"> 
        The table have got processing instructions you are looking altered to modify
        pagination. </report>
    </rule>
  </pattern>
</schema>
```

against this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <?PubTbl row rht="0.76in"?>  
</root>
```

using Oxygen 14's schematron implementation I get the following message:

```
Warning: unrecognized element svrl:schematron-output
```

When I download http://schematron.googlecode.com/files/ant-schematron-2010-04-14.jar and use iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl out of it to compile the schematron, then run that against the sample xml I get the following svrl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<svrl:schematron-output xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
                        xmlns:schold="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron"
                        xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
                        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                        title="Forcing vertical space in content within tables"
                        schemaVersion="iso"><!--   
           
           
         --><svrl:active-pattern document="file:/Users/nunes/Desktop/tmp/test.xml"
                        id="vert-space-tables_pattern"
                        name="Forcing vertical space in content within tables"/>
</svrl:schematron-output>
```

which when I then run against iso_schematron_message.xsl from the same jar, I also get the message:

```
Warning: unrecognized element svrl:schematron-output
```

When I diff your debug.xslt with the xsl that I generated using the stylesheet from the specified jar (after running Oxygen's tidy on them both to normalize whitespace) I see these differences:

```
--- debug.xslt  2012-11-10 00:19:39.000000000 -0800
+++ iso.xsl     2012-11-10 00:19:14.000000000 -0800
@@ -310 +310 @@
-      test="contains(., 'breakpenalty=&#34;-10000&#34;') or contains(., 'breakpenalty=&#34;2000&#34;') or contains(.,'rht=')">
+      test="contains(.,'rht=')">
@@ -312 +312 @@
-        test="contains(., 'breakpenalty=&#34;-10000&#34;') or contains(., 'breakpenalty=&#34;2000&#34;') or contains(.,'rht=')"
+        test="contains(.,'rht=')"
```

Are you sure you're using the schematron that you've pasted above and parsing it with the correct stylesheet?

Comment: Ah didn't see that it was working in Oxygen but failing in ant, I suspect ant is your problem not the schematron. Sorry I'm not helping much :(

Comment: Hi nine9ths, thanks for your help. you have been putting your efforts to help me out.

Comment: yes i had mistakenly added a different debug.xslt last time. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: created an xml document`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?oxygen SCHSchema="test-processing-instruction.sch" type="xml"?>
<root>
    <?PubTbl row rht="0.76in"?>  
</root> ` <br/> as you can see I have added a processing instruction in the xml document which is Oxygen specific, and when the xml document is validated the processing instructions related messages are shown in Message frame as follows **Has processing instruction with text value as rht which is not good. (contains(.,'rht=')) [report] **, from which we can conculde that processing instructions are recognized in Oxygen Editor.

Comment: The schematron used for above observation is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" id="foo_schema" queryBinding="xslt2" schemaVersion="iso"><title>A Schematron to check that processing-instructions are validated</title>    <pattern id="foo_pattern"><title>A Schematron to check that processing-instructions are validated</title><rule id="foo_rule2" context="processing-instruction(PubTbl)" abstract="false"><report test="contains(.,'rht=')">Has processing instruction with text value as rht which is not good.</report></rule></pattern>
</schema>`

Comment: But when the same schematron file mentioned above when passed through ISO schematron pipleline using ant **ant-schematron-2010-04-14.jar ** or using ant target as mentioned below produces an svrl ouptput shows that processing-instruction rule is not fired, from which we can conclude that processing instructions are not recognized through this process. With that we get to the point how these processinginstructions schematron rules are recognized in Oxygen XML Editor.is this a functionality added by oxygen or ISO schematorn validates processing instructions but my schematron schema has mistakes?

Comment: `<svrl:schematron-output xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"                        xmlns:schold="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron"                        xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"                        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"                        title="A Schematron to check that processing-instructions are validated" schemaVersion="iso"><svrl:active-pattern document="simple.xml" id="foo_pattern" name="A Schematron to check that processing-instructions are validated"/></svrl:schematron-output>`

Comment: the reason could be the apply-templates (mentioned below which is present at bottom of the debug.xslt file), I have noticed that apply-templates only processes element nodes that way it never gets to processing-instrucitons gets handled, is this why?

`<xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="-2" mode="M1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="M1"/>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: I have found the fix finally. it is a bug in the iso_schematron_skeleton_for_saxon.xsl present in "ant-schematron-2010-04-14.jar". The stylesheet parameter 'only-child-elements' should have a value of 'false', but when schematron schema rule context attribute has processing-instructions or comment, the value turns as 'true' and that is causing the problem                                       `<xsl:param name="only-child-elements">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//iso:rule[contains(@context,'(')]">true</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:param>`